# Questions answering engine With Google API

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Programming a "question answering engine" based on an internal or cloud DB, is a very complicated thing to do, especially when the questions are asked in natural language.

However, Google does it prety well recently. Is there a way to use Googles high performance for that? Does Google give that service to use their platform for enterprise QA? 
Thank you
Gal

Comment: I am curious about this as well... I currently am working on a QA system - trying to improve accuracy currently I am just doing google searches / bing searches and using those results.  Im interested in finding other methods.  The 2 below aren't great

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide answers in natural language to questions in natural language, you should check out the [Wolfram Alpha API's](https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/) or the [WebKnox API](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/webknox-question-answering).

Comment: I've looked into both of these wolfram alpha is really only good for quantitate data - not general purpose questions say potentially trivia about sports or movies.  Webknox really lacks as well when it comes to potential broad questions.

Comment: I think this is more of an issue with expert systems being designed for a limited domain. General Knowledge, being not a specific problem domain, but rather a wide array of possible questions/problems, makes it difficult to provide a reliable service for a wide range of questions. Because every expert system is just as good as the knowledge corpus it relies on.